# The geometrical multiplicity of the nilpotent matrices

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, eigenvector

The following point is well-known in the literature.

**Theorem. Let $A$ be a non-negative matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. If $A$ is nil-potent, there is  a permutation matrix $P$ such that $P^tAP$ is strictly upper triangular.**

Suppose that $B$ is a nilpotent matrix whose entries are all either $0$ or $1$. Let us denote $\mathcal{P}_B$ the set of all permutations $P$ such that $P^tBP$ is strictly upper triangular. For a given $P\in\mathcal{P}_B$, we let $\alpha_P$ be the number of zeros of the super-diagonal of $P^tBP$.

> Q. Let us put,
> $$\alpha_G=\min \alpha_P$$
> where the minimum is taken over the permutations $P$ in  $\mathcal{P}_B$. Can we say that $$g-1\leq\alpha_G\leq g$$ where  $g$ is just the geometrical multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$ of $B$?

Comment: In your above example , $g=\alpha_G=2$.